# Should a god have more or less power when in a physical body?

Tags: magic, warfare, gods, races

I'm writing a fantasy novel titled "Seraphim Divided." In the novel, there is a god known as Thorolax (The Midnight Harbinger). I want to have him be introduced as an ethereal being who has to rely on influence more than direct confrontation. As the story goes on, I was thinking he should inhabit the body of a race known as the Ladin Puratel — as human bodies are not strong enough.

What are the pros and cons for my goals of these two scenarios?
(A)  Have powerful magic when possessing the body of a L. Puratel and weak magic in spirit form.
(B)  Have weak magic when possessing a L. Puratel but powerful magic in spirit form.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Our community is dedicated to solving worldbuilding problems, not to provide a base for opinion surveys. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our standards.

Comment: "Thorolax the Midnight Harbinger" sounds like some kind of pharmceutical for dealing with certain kinds of intestinal upset...

Comment: Thorolax sounds like a contraction of "thorough relaxation". Some kind of relaxing drug?

Comment: @StarfishPrime, Thoradia was a product of [radioactive quackery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_quackery)

Comment: @Anixx without wishing to explain the joke, have a search for exlax and dulcolax (to name but two examples).

Comment: @L.Dutch humankind's boundless ability to invent and believe in magical cure-alls never ceases to amaze and depress me.

Comment: @StarfishPrime purges gently without interrupting sleep

Answer (score 0):

**Less**

You can only fit a portion of a god inside a vessel. God do this for direct physical access to something plus if the body dies, the power is returned. In the worse case where said body is trapped, the ethereal god can still continue minus the power invested.

Whilst not a god, in the manga "[Ghost in the Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell)" after the Major and Puppet Master join to create a super powerful AI, the Major admits she can no longer fit inside a human body so creates combat ready shells which contains her intellect and just the skills she needs.

Comment: what you referenced says "The "ghost in the machine" is British philosopher Gilbert Ryle's description of René Descartes' mind-body dualism. " you probably meant Ghost in the shell, which in any case is not a god.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but there's a few things to consider. If he's a spirit, wouldn't he be unable to interact with the physical world in most physical manners? So, perhaps yes, he is weaker in physical form, but he is much more capable of interacting with the physical plane of existence?